# Finding the Covariance matrix of this vector - answer provided only approval needed...

Tags: probability

Assume that the vector $z$ of length $N$ is distributed as $$ z  \sim \,\, \text{i.i.d} \,\ \mathcal{N} (0,\sigma^2)$$

Now assume that we have vector $a$ of length $N$ $$a= \sum_{j=1}^K a_j $$

What is the Variance of $$ a^* z$$

My attempt

$$\text{Cov}(a^*z)= a^* \text{Cov}(z) a = a^* ( \sigma_n^2 I) a\stackrel{}{=}a^*a (\sigma^2 )= (\sum_{}a_j^*\sum a_j)\sigma^2$$

Is it correct? 
If $a_j^* a_j=1\, \forall j $, is the resultant $$K^2\sigma^2$$
Thanks

Comment: Is $a$ a sum of vectors?

Comment: yes that is correct... $a_j$ and $n$ are of same length

Comment: What about the sum sign? $n$, I suppose, is, say, $N$. And what is the relationship between the dimension of $a$ and this $n$?

Comment: Im sorry i had very bad notation i changed it..let me know if its good now

Comment: I think your $\sigma_n$ is just $\sigma$ and at last you assume vectors $a_i^*a_j=1 \forall i,j$. Then your result is true.